# Parse server Full Text Search - Error generating response. Error: A search term is required

Tags: parse-platform

I had written cloud code function in Parse server using fullText search syntax. I am getting below error:

> Error generating response. Error: A search term is required

How can I solve the issue?

```
var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(User);
userQuery.fullText("name", searchTerm); // searchTerm is string here
```

...find query syntax

Answer (score 0):

Using `String(searchTerm)` worked.